# Feature request? Ability to create an object via an array of key names in jq

Tags: json, object, key, jq

I'm an intermediate-to-advanced user of jq 1.5 and 1.6.  I'm iterating over an array of objects (let's say, keyed by the names of the first ten digits).  I have an array of strings stored in variable $odd_fields (["one","three",...,"nine"]).  Without using a convoluted iterative process (since I can do this statically with only map({one,three,...,nine}), I'd like to be able to re-cast my array of objects into an array of objects with reference to my array of keys, and in that order, like map({$odd_fields[]}).

After hundreds of attempts, I can't seem to do it in one throw without a static list of members.  I *have* been able to approximate this by creating an array of UNwanted keys and mapping del($unwanted_keys[]), but I don't care what keys I'm throwing away (and I have no confidence that the 50th object doesn't have one extra key that I don't want), only what keys I want to keep (or create, if missing), so that every object in the array has the same arbitrary keys (my keys) in the same order (suitable for @csv).

This is a general need not directly related to a specific JSON glob or specific set of keys, hence no sample JSON.

Most attempts that don't generate syntax or reference errors give me an array of objects [{"odd_fields":["one","three",...,"nine"]},...], or, some iterative processes give me just the values of the keys I want.  I want whole consistent subset objects as if any key not in my list was never present.

Additionally, any wizard out there who can tell me -- while iterating through an object, is there any way to determine what is/was the key to "."?  Similar to:  {"one":1,"two":2,"three":3}|map(.|my_key)  (where function my_key reveals what .'s key is).  I realize there's an easier way to do the above example, but I would like to be able to determine .'s key in other, less direct, code.  I don't need to use it to rip all keys from an object, just one key from an arbitrary ".".

Comment: I have not down-voted your question, but you will likely get more downvotes unless you edit it in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.  Even though your question is generic, pleased provide relevant examples. Also, I would suggest editing this Q so that it only asks one question, and ask your second question separately, following those guidelines.

Comment: Your question is confusing and too long to read and not in an appropriate format. Please ask your question in a better and quicker way so that we could help you.

Comment: Apologies.  Long-time reader, first-time poster, and I whipped this out quickly from work without considering etiquette or conciseness.  I will do better next time. Thanks for the constructive criticism.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recast an object using the keys and key ordering in an array, $array:

```
def recast($array):
  . as $in
  | reduce $array[] as $k ({}; .[$k] = $in[$k]);
```

You could use this with your array as input as follows:

```
map(recast($odd_fields))
```

You may wish to tweak this with respect to missing and/or extra keys.

### As a one-liner

A compact, reduce-free version:

```
map([$array[] as $p|{($p):.[$p]}]|add)
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted.  A bit more verbose than I hoped, but not a convoluted iterative process, and actually keyable inside a map() to avoid function declaration.  Thanks so much!